# Removing font files from Font Awesome - SIL OFL license

Tags: licensing, font

I would like to add to my Website the package "Font Awesome". I would like to use only some font files (which are covered by the [SIL OFL 1.1 license](https://opensource.org/licenses/OFL-1.1)) and the necessary CSS to use it.
It is OK to delete the other files and upload what remains to my website (keeping the original license, of course)? What I am supposed to do? Am I required to do anything else, like changing or editing something?

Comment: The license is pretty easy to read, the requirements (what you are supposed to do) are written in plain English. Please explain which part of the license language is confusing you and where you require specific help.

Answer (score 3):

If you only plan to use the font files that are covered by the SIL OFL 1.1 license, it is generally okay to delete the other files and use only what you need for your website. Modify the font files in any way, you may also need to indicate that your modifications are not endorsed by the creators of the font and that they are not responsible for any issues that may arise as a result of your modifications.

---

https://fontawesome.com/license/free

> Attribution is required by MIT, SIL OFL, and CC BY licenses. Downloaded Font Awesome Free files already contain embedded comments with sufficient attribution, so you shouldn't need to do anything additional when using these files normally.
>
> We've kept attribution comments terse, so we ask that you do not actively work to remove them from files, especially code . They're a great way for folks to learn about Font Awesome.